# Docker Desktop unable to connect

Tags: docker

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  213.3MB
Step 1/14 : FROM python:3.9
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unable to connect to xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xx. Do you need an HTTP proxy?

 *  The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t python-wa "."" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I am getting the above error on docker desktop for windows:

It was working absolutely fine but suddenly it is stopped.

Many suggestions suggested me to restart but had no luck in fixing it.

Any idea what might what be causing this issue ?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include a [mcve]; include the code, commands, and other instructions needed to reproduce the issue.  Make sure to include all of these artifacts as plain text, since PNG files can be hard or impossible to read, reproduce, and search for later.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by Force Point which was blocking that IP.
Once disabled the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a network issue if you are behind a corporate proxy or poor network connection.

You can try changing the network connection.

If you are using Docker desktop on windows, you can restart docker-desktop and check whether the issue persists.

Comment: Nope tried everything . It was working smoothly but then suddenly today it started showing this error message

Comment: @SanketWagh Are you behind proxy network?